# MySQL - data encoded as charset windows-1251 not showing on the server

Tags: php, mysql, database, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying to deal with an old server that was resurrected after many years. The problem is that the DB is in a weird state.

The website reads the information from the DB with charset ="windows-1251". The whole table and the fields in the table seen in phpMyAdmin have collation "cp-1251", which I think is the same as windows=1251. If the text is written in latin everything is displayed properly, but if I write the text in Bulgarian it won't work. Any ideas how to fix the DB issue? I have access to the phpMyAdmin & the admin panel of the website.

I was thinking to switch the charset & collation to utf-8 but I get "?" everywhere. Also I looked up similar websites and I saw that they were using charset = windows-1251 for the same fields, which makes me think that the data in the table is not right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use MySQL's `CHARACTER SET utf8` or `cp1251`.

You will need to switch to that charset throughout

- the bytes in your client
- the connection (see `set_charaset()` in PHP)
- the column/table (`CHARACTER SET ...`)
- html meta.

For further discussion of the question marks, see [Trouble with utf8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

In particular, the data was lost as you stored it into the table.

Comment: Thanks! I converted the database to utf-8 and now all new information is seen. Now is that the old data is still in cp1251 and I need to convert it, I found out that I can do this by dumping it and importing it as utf-8. The problem is that I have access only to the web hosting Control Panel & I have not set up anything on my computer. Due to this, I have no idea how to do this, could you help me?

Comment: Which situation do you have:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases  (Caution:  That writeup is aimed at "having latin1, wanting utf8"; you "have cp1251, want utf8".)